# Cannot run `loadData()` after saving RDS file and reading RDS file using `saveRDS` & `readRDS` in Seurat

Tags: r, seurat

I want to load multiple sample data(pbmc16 and pbmc45), and integrate by following the tutorial below

- Performing integration on datasets normalized with SCTransform
  https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/integration_introduction.html
- performing integration on datasets normalized with sctransform-1

What I did:

1. I performed the pre-processing step (filtering) and SCtransform in each sample, and then save each data with the code

```r
saveRDS(pbmc16, file = "../output/pbmc16_Seurat_Guided_Clustering_Tutorial.rds")
saveRDS(pbmc45, file = "../output/pbmc45_Seurat_Guided_Clustering_Tutorial.rds")
> pbmc16; type S4 [20542x20700](SeuratObject:: Seurat) assays; list [2]
> meta.data; list [20700x8] (S3:data.frame)
```

2. read each sample data by using `readRDS` function

```r
pbmc16 <- readRDS("../output/pbmc16_Seurat_Guided_Clustering_Tutorial.rds")
pbmc45 <- readRDS("../output/pbmc45_Seurat_Guided_Clustering_Tutorial.rds")
```

3. After that, I want to load the data as shown in the tutorial

```r
(LoadData("ifnb"))
LoadData(pbmc16)
LoadData(pbmc45)
```

Then I got this error

```
> LoadData(pbmc16) Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 'match'
> requires vector arguments
```

*Problem*: I don't know how to load each data and integrate the multiple data.

Could you please suggest me the recommended code or advice?

Comment: Hi, you seem to be following the tutorial on the web which unfortunately is not up to date with the package code (in current manual in the web doesn't seem to exists a LoadData function).